# Time Zone con Carbon Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, carbon

Estoy usando la libreria de Carbon para controlar las fechas en mi proyecto y algo no esta funcionando bien.

Estoy creando una nueva fecha, y asignandole la zona horaria pero la hora me las arroja mal.

```
$fecha_actual = new Carbon();
$fecha_actual=$fecha_actual->setTimezone('America/La_Paz');
```

Esto es lo que tengo, actualmente son las 20:00, pero cuando llamo a esta funcion, me devuelve esto.

```
"2021-12-24T23:57:14.242805Z"
```

Alguien tiene idea de que podria ser?

Comment: Veo que aun no has aceptado mi respuesta ni tampoco has hecho ningún comentario al respecto. Si mi respuesta resuelve tu pregunta te recomiendo la aceptes para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede abierta eternamente. Te paso un enlace donde explican como aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200

Answer (score 1):

Diria que la fecha es correcta para la zona horaria que le has puesto, pero fíjate en la `Z` final, que indica que es la correspondiente al formato UTC (la hora del meridiano de Greenwich).

Mira este [mapa](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zona_hor%C3%A0ria#/media/Fitxer:World_Time_Zones_Map.png) de las zonas horarias, la del UTC se corresponde con la del meridiano de Greenwich (0).

Para convertir esa hora UTC a tu zona horaria prueba con esto:

```
$fecha_actual = "2021-12-24T23:57:14.242805Z";
$time = strtotime($fecha_actual);
$fechaLocal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
echo $fechaLocal;
```

Y si no te funciona entonces fuerzalo así:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
$fecha_actual = "2021-12-24T23:57:14.242805Z";
$time = strtotime($fecha_actual);
$fechaLocal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
echo $fechaLocal;
```